# asp.net mvc web api 2 custom logger + controller lifecycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller

story:I have following component in my asp.net mvc 5 web api project(using ef code first)

1. myBaseController :  base api controller class
2. myLogger : my costume logger class

   `class myBaseController  { MyLogger Logger; }`

   `class MyLogger
       {
        public addLog(Log log)
           {
            db.logs.add(log);
            db.saveChanges();
            }
        }`

Each api controller use `base.logger.addLog(new log("somethings"))` and the log committed to database immediately.

Problem: I want `MyLogger` class be able to collect all log in memory and some where add theme to database at once.
I put it in

`protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    logger.AddRange(_logs);
    }`

but it doesn't work,it seems objects are not available in this method or grabbed from memory

How it should be handled?

Comment: Stick the logs in session.

Comment: How do you want to persist the log entries? By request? By session? By an arbitrary timeframe?  By design, each controller will be 'newed-up' by the framework for each action which is why you're seeing that behavior.  You'll need to persist the log to memory if you want it to persist across requests.

Comment: Of course  log entries should be inserted to database at the end of each request(for each action call).@PhilCooper

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to collect records in memory separately. Because EF will do that for you. For instance `db.logs.add` means, please add it to memory. But when you call `SaveChanges` it will commit all of the in-memory collected data to the database at once. So you will need to implement the `unit of work pattern (UoW)`. By using this pattern, you will have only `one context per request` and then at the end of the request you will call the `SaveChanges` method `once`. You shouldn't have multiple `SaveChanges` everywhere in your codes, this is your problem right now. Your `addLog` method calls `SaveChanges`, your other methods call `SaveChanges` and so on.

More info from Microsoft: [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Thnaks Vahid,your solution is cool,So where should I add last SaveChanges method? Should i paperer a costume filter attribute? @VahidN

Comment: You should have only one context per request and then inject it using dependency injection. More info in Persian: http://www.dotnettips.info/post/842 and also http://www.dotnettips.info/courses/topic/5/3697d84b-8c79-4722-875f-a35920fe88ba

Comment: Thank you,let me try it @VahidN

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your entries in memory during request cycle and at end of request you can save those entries into database

```
 protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
      //get entries from memory/session/cache whatever your source to store entries
      //do stuff to save entries
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally create ***ActionFilterAttributes***, and place it on action methods where I want to log any activity.

### [TraceMvcAttribute](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Debugging/TraceMvcAttribute.cs#L12)

```
public class TraceMvcAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   // IoC container will inject this dependencies.
   public IWebUserSession WebUserSession { get; set; }
   public IDateTime DateTime { get; set; }
   public ITraceListener TraceListener { get; set; }

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      var traceLog = new TraceLog
      {
         Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
         Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
         Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filterContext.ActionParameters),
         PerformedOn = this.DateTime.Now,
         PerformedBy = WebUserSession?.UserName
      };
      TraceListener.AddTraceLogAsync(traceLog);
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }
}
```

### TraceApiAttribute

Web API filter is a little bit different from MVC filter. I do not have it in [my sample code](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/tree/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Debugging) at Git; in case you might want to take a look at it.

```
public class TraceApiAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filters-are-singletons
        // All filter attributes in Web API are effectively singleton instances that exist 
        // for the entire lifetime of the application. We must use service location, 
        // since we need per-request services in your filters.
        var requestScope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
        var datetime = requestScope.GetService(typeof(IDateTime)) as IDateTime;
        var webUserSession = requestScope.GetService(typeof(IWebUserSession)) as IWebUserSession;
        var traceListener = requestScope.GetService(typeof(ITraceListener)) as ITraceListener;

        var traceLog = new TraceLog
        {
            Controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
            Action = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
            Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actionContext.ActionArguments.Where(x => x.Key != "request").ToList()),
            PerformDateTime = datetime.Now,
            PerformBy = webUserSession?.UserName
        };
        traceListener.AddTraceLogAsync(traceLog);
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

I then view the log history like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin#admin-trace-log-detail) -

[image]